# Getting all combinations of splitting an array into two equally sized groups in Julia

Tags: combinations, julia

Given an array of 20 numbers, I would like to extract all possible combinations of two groups, with ten numbers in each, order is not important.

`combinations([1, 2, 3], 2)`

in Julia will give me all possible combinations of two numbers drawn from the array, but I also need the ones that were not drawn...

Comment: Maybe combinations should return both groups of values. You may want to open an issue about this API matter.

Comment: Doing so by default would kill the performance of `combinations(1:1000, 2)`, which must be a common case and currently is very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setdiff` to determine the items missing from any vector, e.g.,

```
y = setdiff(1:5, [2,4])
```

yields `[1,3,5]`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there might be duplicated values, ie. if we had [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7] and wanted to split it into two groups, setdiff() would not give us the "remaining values", it would remove all duplicates.

Comment: Then don't have repeated values. Just do `combinations([1:9],4)` and get your actual values by `val[index]`, where `index` comes from `combinations` (or `setdiff` on the result of `combinations`) and `val=[1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7]`. This should be more efficient than the version based on `removeall!`.

Comment: In fact, even better than `setdiff` might be something like `flag=falses(9); flag[index]=true; {value[flag], value[!flag]}`.

Comment: Getting actual values by val[index] is brilliant - a great way of turning it around - and should be a lot more efficient than my version above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After playing around for a bit, I came up with this code, which seems to work. I'm sure it could be written much more elegantly, etc.

```
function removeall!(remove::Array, a::Array)
    for i in remove
        if in(i, a)
            splice!(a, indexin([i], a)[1])
        end
    end
end

function combinationgroups(a::Array, count::Integer)
    result = {}
    for i in combinations(a, count)
        all = copy(a)
        removeall!(i, all)
        push!(result, { i; all } )
    end
    result
end

combinationgroups([1,2,3,4],2)

6-element Array{Any,1}:
 {[1,2],[3,4]}
 {[1,3],[2,4]}
 {[1,4],[2,3]}
 {[2,3],[1,4]}
 {[2,4],[1,3]}
 {[3,4],[1,2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @tholy's comment about instead of using the actual numbers, I could use positions (to avoid problems with numbers not being unique) and setdiff to get the "other group" (the non-selected numbers), I came up with the following. The first function grabs values out of an array based on indices (ie. arraybyindex([11,12,13,14,15], [2,4]) => [12,14]). This seems like it could be part of the standard library (I did look for it, but might have missed it).

The second function does what combinationgroups was doing above, creating all groups of a certain size, and their complements. It can be called by itself, or through the third function, which extracts groups of all possible sizes. It's possible that this could all be written much faster, and more idiomatical.

```
function arraybyindex(a::Array, indx::Array)
    res = {}
    for e in indx
        push!(res, a[e])
    end

    res
end
function combinationsbypos(a::Array, n::Integer)
    res = {}
    positions = 1:length(a)
    for e in combinations(positions, n)          
        push!(res, { arraybyindex(a, e) ; arraybyindex(a, setdiff(positions, e)) })
    end
    res
end

function allcombinationgroups(a::Array)
    maxsplit = floor(length(a) / 2)
    res = {}
    for e in 1:5
        println("Calculating for $e, so far $(length(res)) groups calculated")
        push!(res, combinationsbypos(a, e))
    end
    res
end
```

Running this in IJulia on a 3 year old MacBook pro gives

```
@time c=allcombinationgroups([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
println(length(c))
c

Calculating for 1, so far 0 groups calculated
Calculating for 2, so far 20 groups calculated
Calculating for 3, so far 210 groups calculated
Calculating for 4, so far 1350 groups calculated
Calculating for 5, so far 6195 groups calculated
Calculating for 6, so far 21699 groups calculated
Calculating for 7, so far 60459 groups calculated
Calculating for 8, so far 137979 groups calculated
Calculating for 9, so far 263949 groups calculated
Calculating for 10, so far 431909 groups calculated
elapsed time: 11.565218719 seconds (1894698956 bytes allocated)
Out[49]:
616665

616665-element Array{Any,1}:
 {{1},{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}}
 {{2},{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}}
  ⋮                                                       
 {{10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11}}
 {{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}
```

ie. 53,334 groups calculated per second.

As a contrast, using the same outer allcombinationgroups function, but replacing the call to combinationsbypos with a call to combinationgroups (see previous answer), is 10x slower.

I then rewrote the array by index group using true or false flags as suggested by @tholy (I couldn't figure out how to get it work using [], so I used setindex! explicitly, and moved it into one function. Another 10x speedup! 616,665 groups in 1 second!

Final code (so far):

```
function combinationsbypos(a::Array, n::Integer)
    res = {}
    positions = 1:length(a)
    emptyflags = falses(length(a))
    for e in combinations(positions, n)       
        flag = copy(emptyflags)
        setindex!(flag, true, e)
        push!(res, {a[flag] ; a[!flag]} )
    end
    res
end

function allcombinationgroups(a::Array)
    maxsplit = floor(length(a) / 2)
    res = {}
    for e in 1:maxsplit
        res = vcat(res, combinationsbypos(a, e))
    end
    res
end
```